# 「Powershell ウインドウをここに開く」からPowershellを実行した場合、javaコマンドが使えない

Tags: java, powershell

環境変数などを設定し、Powershellを普通に開いて「java -version」などを実行すると正常に動くのですが、「Powershell ウインドウをここに開く」からPowershellを実行した場合、以下のようなエラーが出て実行できません。

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

原因はわからないでしょうか？

Comment: 「Powershell ウインドウをここに開く」時は[エクスプローラを全て閉じないと環境変数が反映されません](https://www.scriptlife.jp/contents/programming/2017/07/04/windows-cmd-env/)。念のため再起動すればエラーは解消されませんか？

Comment: @payaneco ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答が形式上存在しない状態になってるので転載します。
payanecoさんより：
「Powershell ウインドウをここに開く」時はエクスプローラを全て閉じないと環境変数が反映されません。